# Should custom key objects be immutable ?If yes , then why?

Tags: java, collections, immutability

Okay I want to have custom user defined objects as keys in my `HashMap` instead of say `String`. Should the candidate objects be immutable ? I read somewhere that the best practice is to make them immutable but I can not figure out the reason myself .

Comment: If `hashCode` and/or `equals` can change throughout the duration of the key object lifetime, you are violating an invariant that is required for `HashMap` to work. There are no guarantees that the `HashMap` will be able to locate a value associated with that key when querying it, though `keySet`, `values`, and `entrySet` will still contain the key, value, and `Map.Entry` corresponding to the key-value pair, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a mutable key in a HashMap, then it will end up in the wrong bucket, which totally breaks the Map.

1. insert key, hashCode() is called, bucket assigned
2. change key, hashCode changes, no longer matches the bucket
3. look up by (new) key, hashCode() leads to the wrong bucket, value not found
4. look up by (old) key, hashCode() leads to the "correct" bucket, but now the key found there is no longer `equal` (because it is the "new" key now), so it is also discarded

If you have a mutable key in a TreeMap, then it will end up in the wrong position of the tree, which is supposed to be sorted (and that happens at insertion-time). Basically same flow as above.

And since we like similes around here, this is like changing your name in an existing phonebook with a magic marker without printing a whole new book: So your new name "Smith" will still be listed between "John" and "Johnston" (where no one will look for it), and no one will find it between "Smart" and "Smithers" (where they are looking for it). TreeMap works just like a phonebook.

Comment: you mean lookup by the original key and not the changed key , right ?

Comment: Lookup by the changed key will lead to a bucket that is empty. Lookup by the original key will find an entry, but it will no longer be `equal`. Error in both cases.

Comment: in step 4 , would would the value found not be equal , we didn't touch the value at all . We just changed the key in step 2 ?

Comment: The old value is not equal to the new value. And by value, I mean key. Will edit with clearer wording.

Comment: One can have a key of a mutable *type* in a hashTable without difficulty, provided that no reference to that key is ever received by any code that mutate it while the key is stored in the table.  If one wants to allow for the existence of "live views" of objects within the table, and one is not using multi-threading, it may even be helpful to have the object to which the table holds a reference be truly mutable, but provide some form of update notifications so that each change will remove the old item from the table and add the new one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes they should be immutable as they would not function well as keys if they could be changed. Imagine buying a lock and key for your house, but then deciding you'd like to make the key prettier by hammering it into a different shape. It wouldn't work very well, would it? The same principles apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you update key from somewhere else then you can no longer lookup the value stored for that key.